# Regex for validating username

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried lots of regex patterns but I couldn't find a perfect regex which does the following (min. 3 char and max. 30, special characters can be allowed, if all characters are only special characters it should return false).

Expectation:

1. "ben":true,(3 char satisfied)
2. "ab":false, (3 char not satisfied)
3. "ben franklin":true, (space can be allowed)
4. "ben_franklin":true, (special char can be allowed)
5. "ben@:true, (special char and min 3 char satisfied)
6. "%#$":false, (though 3char ,but its all special char)
7. "ben#franklin":true,
8. "be'franklin":true
9. "&%^$@#!*&^":false

Comment: I suppose if you have 10 special chars in a row it's also false? `"&%^$@#!*&^":false`?

Comment: @xdhmoore yup it should be false

Comment: is it required that you solve it with only one regex? if you split the task into two regexes, the problem becomes much easier. Whitelist first  ( check if it has only the characters that you want and in the desired length ) and accept them, then blacklist second ( check if the string only contains special characters ) and reject those

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar that is what I was also going to suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "special characters", you mean any non-alphanumeric characters, you may use the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9]).{3,30}$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Axyd2Z/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```regex
^                   # Beginning of the string.
(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])   # Must contain at least one alphanumeric (English) character.
.{3,30}             # Match any character (special or not) between 3 and 30 times.
$                   # End of string.
```

**Further adjustments:**

- If you want to add more characters to the "not special chars", you may add them inside the character class. For example, to add the space char, you may use `[A-Za-z0-9 ]`.
- If you want to limit the "special characters" to a particular set of characters, then you may replace `.{3,30}` with `[A-Za-z0-9@#$%....]{3,30}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just do this with 2 passes:

```
let str = "ben#franklin";
let result = !!(str.match(/^[a-z\s!@#$%^&_-]{3,30}$/g) && str.match(/^.*[a-z].*$/g));
console.log(result);
```

1. Check for valid characters.
2. Make sure at least one a-z character.

You didn't mention numbers or uppercase characters, so I didn't add them.